# How can I skip some users while migrating from svn to git?

Tags: git, svn, migration, author

I've done file with authors for --authors-file parameter of git svn clone.
And I want skip some users cause they left our team. How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "skip"?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't simply ignore the commits those ex-employees made, and since you cannot have empty names in Git commits, you basically have three options:

1. You leave them as-is and use their names/emails as they were at the time they worked at the company.
2. You use some kind of placeholder 'anonymous' user/email.
3. You claim ownership over those commits and set your own name/email as the substitute author.

Options 1 and 2 are valid since Git names/emails can be anything you like, and don't have to link to an actual person or Active Directory login (even when using Git on TFS).

Personally, I'd recommend leaving them as-is, because you probably want to be able to audit old code. Replacing old authors is basically rewriting history and you could be causing yourself future problems there. Also, you don't want to go changing commits and force-pushing your Git repo when current employees leave your team.